# Talking in the past about someone in the present

Tags: tense, usage

I'm not sure whether I'm able to mix the past with the present and vice versa.

> I spoke to a nice woman yesterday, she was beautiful.
>
> I spoke to a nice woman yesterday, she is beautiful.

> All of my exes were Asian.
>
> All of my exes are Asian.

Comment: You'd normally say *All of my exes **are** Asian* (same as *My **friends are** all Asian*), because there's no surrounding context that might encourage you to "backshift" the verb. But in the past tense context of the woman you spoke to yesterday, it would be *normal* to backshift. So much so that it's hard to imagine any context where it would be "natural" to say *I spoke to a nice woman yesterday. She **is** beautiful.* The only half-way credible context I can think of for that is if ***while saying that second sentence***, you were showing people a picture of the woman you spoke to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above are grammatical. It's really up to you to choose the tense that is best. If you use `was` instead of `is` (or `were` instead of `are`), you are implying that the event is definitely from the past. If you use present tense, it implies *immediacy* and that the condition might still be true now.

For example, you might say the following:

> Yesterday I spoke with a nice woman I met at the park and will probably never see again; she **was** beautiful.

> Yesterday I spoke with the nice woman who lives next door, she **is** beautiful.

If your Asian exes go back many years of your life -- or if some or all of them are no longer living -- then you might want to use past tense. Similarly, if you are an old man and looking back on your life, past tense might be preferable.

However, if you have dated many Asian women or have dated them recently, you might use present tense, which implies that you are still racking up Asian exes.

Answer (score 1):

> I spoke to a nice woman yesterday, she was beautiful.

> I spoke to a nice woman yesterday, she is beautiful.

> All of my exes were Asian.

> All of my exes are Asian.

For example 1, as that nice woman you spoke to yesterday is probably still around and beautiful, the present tense would be fine.

For example 2, as a person's race will not change, the present tense would be fine.